# Ansible playbook skip task on last node in serial execution

Tags: ansible

I want to run some ansible task on 4 servers one by one, i.e. on serial manner. But there will be a pause in between. So, I have added the pause at last in the playbook, but I want it to be skipped on last server. Otherwise it will wait for no reason. Please let me know how to implement this.

```
---
- hosts: server1,server2,server3,server4
  serial: 1
  vars_files:
    - ./vars.yml

  tasks:
    - name: Variable test
      pause:
        minutes: 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really interesting problem which forced me to look for an actual solution. Here is the quickest one I came up with.

The [ansible special variables documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) defines the `ansible_play_hosts_all` variable as follow

> List of all the hosts that were targeted by the play

The list of hosts in that var is in the order it was found inside the inventory.

Provided you use the default inventory [order](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#play) for your play, you can set a test that will trigger the task unless the current host is the last one in that list:

```
when: inventory_hostname != ansible_play_hosts_all[-1]
```

As reported by @Vladimir in the comments below, if you change the play order parameter from default, this approach will break.

Comment: This is exactly what I want, It solved my problem. Thanks much :)

Comment: Do not change [order](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#play). Take care.

Comment: @VladimirBotka: thanks for this return. Tested and answer updated to take this into account.

Answer (score 1):

The playbook below does the job

```
- hosts: all
  serial: 1

  vars:
    completed: false

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        completed: true

    - block:
        - debug:
            msg: All completed. End of play.
        - meta: end_play
      when: "groups['all']|
             map('extract', hostvars, 'completed')|
             list is all"

    - name: Variable test
      pause:
        minutes: 1
```

---

Notes

- see [any/all](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#test-if-a-list-contains-a-value)
- see [Extracting values from containers](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#extracting-values-from-containers)
- see [hostvars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables)

Comment: Is this answer correct even if I limit the hosts? For example if I set the CLI flag `--limit group01a`?